# Sending data to printer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using php I created dynamical table, which contains all students from my database.  I would like now to add an icon of printer, and when user clicks on that icon, to send this table to printer? I saw it on many pages, but how it's done? Tnx in advance...

Comment: `<script>window.print();</script>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use [**`window.print()`**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp).
Example in jQuery:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#print").click(function() {
        window.print();
    });
});
</script>
<a id='print'>Print ME</a>
```

Example in JavaScript:

```
<script>
function printMe() {
    window.print()
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printMe()">
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from `window.print()` it should be noted that JavaScript can't send the data to the printer directly - it can prompt the print dialog for you though. IE6 used to allow that, and visiting certain sites would make for surprises in your printer tray later that evening.

You can bypass the print dialog with a browser plugin.