# Print directly to the default printer without opening print popup window options - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I am printing contents of div using the following code using javascript function as follows:

```
function printDiv(data) 
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

        mywindow.print();

        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }
```

When call this function it opens a popup window and using the print option I can able to print it.

I need print such a way that **When I call print function the print popup should not come, it should directly go to the default printer and do the printing**. How can I achieve it? please guide me.

Comment: Would you **really** want *nefarious* websites just printing whatever they want to your printer without you being able to stop it?   I *really* hope this is not possible (apologies for your requirement).

Comment: I just need this only for my button click action for a particular action only, not for all.@freedomn-m any alternative possible buddy?

Comment: *You* might need it just for your button click action, but I can guarantee that if this was possible, they'll be a website out there that prints war-and-peace (or a continuous stream of dubious images) to your printer without asking.

Comment: If it's for an intranet, you could possibly print server-side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending data to printer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724550/sending-data-to-printer)

Comment: @ freedomn-m Thanks buddy. Cheers!!